# "Google Smart Speaker type Broadcast Notification"

Tags: google-cast

I currently send notifications (via TTS) to cast devices using the default media player. The problem is that this stops the currently running apps.

If I ask my smart speaker:  "OK Google Broadcast Hello There"
It interrupts the current APP, plays the message, then resumes.

What strategy do I need to follow to emulate the ability to send a notification, interrupting any current app, and resuming when the notification completes.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case isn't currently supported. There is also no 3rd party API for that.